# How to use a macro that wil update a pivot table, inside a pivot table update event without causing an infinite loop

Tags: vba, excel

How to use a macro that wil update a pivot table, inside a pivot table update event without causing an infinite loop

```
     Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)

     Dim ONS As Boolean

     If ONS = True Then Exit Sub
     ONS = True

     'Line of code that will update the pivot table

      ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_MSS_Top_Parent_org1"). _
    VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array( _
    "[CA_analysis_0501_final].[MSS Top Parent org].&[0]")

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try simply disabling events:

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)


 'Line of code that will update the pivot table
Application.Enableevents = False
  ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_MSS_Top_Parent_org1"). _
VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array( _
"[CA_analysis_0501_final].[MSS Top Parent org].&[0]")
Application.Enableevents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to consider

1) The `Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate` command will fire regardless of how the pivot table is updated. So if you are updating it with the same macro that is triggered by an update, you will cause an infinate loop

2) What exactly is the `line of code that will update pivot table`? What does this do exactly?

If I were attempting something like this, I'd probably use a `Boolean` to control when exactly the macro fires off, creating a oneshot type method:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
Dim ONS as Boolean

If ONS = True then exit sub

'Line of code that will update the pivot table

ONS = True
End Sub
```

I haven't tested the above code, but booleans are always defaulted to `FALSE`, so when it is switched on at the end of the macro and the macro attempts to fire again, it should exit the sub without getting a chance to update again. The next time a change occurrs, because the value isn't stored anywhere it should be set to `FALSE` again and allow the macro to fire.

Let me know if it works :)

**EDIT**

This simple test proves this method would work:

```
Sub test2()

Dim x As Boolean

If x = True Then MsgBox "its still true"

MsgBox "It's False"

x = True

If x = True Then MsgBox "Set to true"

End Sub
```

the next time the code is run, I still don't see the message "It's Still True" because Excel has forgotten it was set to true the last time. It'll only remain true if held in a variable somewhere and referenced later. Thus creating a oneshot code in your case

Comment: thanks for prompt response. The code that I want to use inside will change the value of one slicer. But once that gets executed it triggers the pivot update event from beginning.. So it runs infintely. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: You should declare the `ONS` variable as `Static` rather than using `Dim`, since as it is, `ONS` will always be `False` on starting the routine. A `Static` variable will preserve its value between calls.

Comment: @citizenkong I'm under the impression that because the pivot table is updated as part of the macro that is triggered by an update, VBA would "remember" the last known condition as the script hasn't actually stopped. If this is wrong, then I'm in agreement that you'll need to change the variable to a `static`

Comment: It might even be better to have the one-shot variable held in a static **function**, just in case...

Comment: @user2691260 edit your question to include your code

Comment: When the slicer value is changed, the sub is executed from beginning and the ONS variable is lost and declared again.. So endless loop is running

Comment: @user2691260 Try what @citizenkong suggested and change `DIM` to `STATIC`, but be aware that you will need to set `ONS` to `FALSE` somewhere else otherwise the code will never run again. So the question is, do you need it to run **everytime** or only when you specify?